# Tuleap - Trackers - Can't edit artifacts

Tags: centos, tuleap

It is impossible to have the little pencil to edit artifact after creation.

I can create an artifact, but after that I can't modify it.

I tried all what is available in config to properly set users rights.

Comment: Could you detail what you mean by _I tried all what is available in config to properly set users rights._

Comment: First I check I'm admin of the tracker. Then I select the tracker, I go to "administration" and I set user permissions to "Have access to all artifacts". Then I go through "field permission" and set to "update" each field for project members.

Comment: Which version of Tuleap are you using? could you share a screenshot of the artifact view of one of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a bug, an artifact was created to track this down: https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=8311

Feel free to jump into the discussion

Comment: I confirm that the fix proposed in the ticket 8311 solves the problem. Is it a convention to mark a topic as closed ?

Comment: Good to hear. Yes, you should approve my answer so ppl can refer to it later.